# How to script to turn off mac window mirroring,

Tags: macos, terminal, system-preferences

So I have 150+ users who are using a mac mini, El Capitan.
I use deploy studio to make an image so I can clean out the junk every so often, on this image I have settings and such that I can regulate, I am not sure how to make it so the first time someone logs in, the windows are not mirrored, (everyone is using dual monitors). Is this possible?
I can make an Apple script to do it just fine, but that isn't acceptable in this case.

Question : How do I set the preference/setting of "mirror windows" to be automatically or always unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link could help your problem : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2750766?tstart=0

Comment: That does not work because you have to log on to your user one time and uncheck the box. I am trying to do it from a deployable standpoint, where that setting is changed to off by default, without having to manually log in and uncheck the box.

Answer (score 0):

The setting for whether a display is mirrored or not is controlled per display using the key "Mirrored" in this file:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist
```

However, that file contains a list of displays, each potentially with a unique identifier. You might be able to lay down the same file on multiple machines provided they all have the same monitor model, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: PS. I am stalking you :)

Comment: I dont mind, you are answering some of my questions!